# Java/C implementation of ANSI X9.19 (Retail MAC)

Tags: java, cryptography

Does anyone have a working version of ANSI X9.19 (aka Retail MAC) calculation code in either Java or C? I tried all the ones found on SO but cannot seem to get it right. My inputs are:

Data:

```
31303030313232303136303432353135333735383030303032363030303030343835383038343837323031353130323330303030303031303030303030303030303031
```

Key:

```
B6E58778DFA2F0A58DF0C6D792734720
```

Expected MAC:

```
 a6a2c109........
```

Comment: Technically MAC is not encryption...changed tags.

Answer (score 3):

The Bouncy Castle provider contains `"DESISO9797MAC"` as algorithm string for `Mac`.

Result:

```
a6a2c109be35bae7
```

---

Note that the `toString` of the service reads:

```
BC: Mac.DESWITHISO9797 -> org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.DES$DES9797Alg3
  aliases: [DESISO9797MAC]
```

and that the last part of the class name `DES9797Alg3` points to [ISO 9797 MAC algorithm 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9797-1#MAC_algorithm_3), which specifies RetailMAC within an international standard document.

The trick is mainly knowing what to look for...

Comment: Normally I would not have bothered answering (asking for references or software), but it's hard to find this algorithm by trial and error due to the different names that the algorithm is known.